# .Navigate() in Gecko Web Browser control problem

Tags: c#, url, gecko, navigateurl

I am using the Gecko Webbrowser control. What I do is to first click button1 to go to the first URL. This works fine!

Then I click button2 to go the almost the same URL. The only difference is that the date is different, 2019-09-26.

If I do that in google chrome, it works fine. But when I click button2 after I have landed on the URL with 2019-09-13 successfully. Nothing happens!

button2 doesn't navigate to the URL here. Why does chrome react when I paste that URL. 
I wonder if I need to reset any cache or something in the Gecko control before navigating somehow?
I tried to navigate to https://www.google.com/ in button2 and that worked fine.

Any ideas would be so helpful!

Thank you!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://app.someurl.com/web?startDate=2019-09-13");
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://app.someurl.com/web?startDate=2019-09-26");
}
private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    geckoWebBrowser1.Update();
}
```

Comment: Tested this and I had no problems. Why do you have geckoWebBrowser1.Update();?

Comment: Hi. Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Tested this and no problems. I created a simple php page to display the query string.

Windows 10 Home / Visual Studio 2019 Developer / Geckofx60.32 (from NuGet)

[image: screenshot]

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost:81/?test=true");
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost:81/?test=false");
}

private void GeckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    geckoWebBrowser1.Update();
    textBox1.Text = geckoWebBrowser1.Url.ToString();
}

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

index.php

```
test = 
<?php echo $_GET["test"]; ?>
```